# F# - For Loop question in F#

Tags: function, f#

I would like to write this kind of program (this is a simple example to explain what i would like to do) :

```
//  #r "FSharp.PowerPack.dll" 

open Microsoft.FSharp.Math

// Definition of my products

let product1 = matrix [[0.;1.;0.]]

let product2 = matrix [[1.;1.;0.]]

let product3 = matrix [[1.;1.;1.]]

// Instead of this (i have hundreds of products) : 

printfn "%A" product1

printfn "%A" product2

printfn "%A" product3

// I would like to do something like this (and it does not work):

for i = 1 to 3 do

printfn "%A" product&i
```

Thank you in advance !!!!!

Comment: You could add `product1` to `productN` to a list, `lst`, and do: `for prod in lst do printfn "%A" prod`. Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of using separate variables for individual matrices, you could use a list of matrices:

```
let products = [ matrix [[0.;1.;0.]] 
                 matrix [[1.;1.;0.]] 
                 matrix [[1.;1.;1.]] ]
```

If your matrices are hard-coded (as in your example), then you can initialize the list using the notation above. If they are calculated in some way (e.g. as a diagonal or permutations or something like that), then there is probably better way to create the list, either using `List.init` or using similar function.

Once you have a list, you can iterate over it using a `for` loop:

```
for product in products do
  printfn "%A" product
```

(In your sample, you're not using the index for anything - but if you needed indexing for some reason, you could create an array using `[| ... |]` and then access elements using `products.[i]`)

Comment: Thank you that's perfect ! I will use the index and therefore the array example ...

Comment: Note that direct index via .[i] works on list as well except that it'll probably have a performance profile in O(n) rather than O(1) for arrays.

Comment: @katter75 : If your question has been answered with your expectations then please don't forget to select then answer as "correct".

Answer (score 1):

Also you can do it like that :

```
matrix    [ [ 0.; 1.; 0. ];
            [ 1.; 1.; 0. ];
            [ 1.; 1.; 1. ]; ]
    |> Seq.iter(fun p -> printf "%A" p)
```